# Laravel 7 - Unaccessible when trying to open site on production

Tags: laravel, nginx, deployment, config

i've deploied my laravel site on my server.
but i got a problem.

1. **First:**
   my files was in the *public_html* folder.
   I got the `403 forbidden` error.
2. **Then**:
   i tried to move them outside the *public_html* folder and only put the laravel's public folder contents onto that.
   it only show "*Nginx* is functioning normally".

I get the next message: 
`The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

and the next log: `[error] 8949#0: *2449542 access forbidden by rule, client: 13.90.224.16, server: marchethiaroye.com, request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "www.marchethiaroye.com"`
 [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xHAP.png)

Please help! It's my first deploiment.

**NB:** the site is working on local

[file configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGE4k.png)  [message i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILY69.png)

Comment: can you share your NGNIX conf file?

Comment: where am i supposed to find that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your laravel project name is 'test'.

And you put 'test' on public_html.

Try open http://IP_ADDR/test/public

Comment: i put all files except public files onto my root dir. And i configured the index.php to require all files from the dir.( the public_html is the public directory of my server)